# How to stop sending RST packets on specific port

Tags: tcp

My VPS is getting SYN-flooded only on port 17236 and 17231. How can I ignore requests from that port? I'm on Debian 8.

Comment: Clos the ports in the firewall. Why are they open? Off topic.

Comment: They aren't open. Do you know what a syn-flood is?